# Relation between payment and invoices in ledgerJournalTrans

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm working on AX 2012 and I need the relation between invoice (account payable->payment journal)  and  payment (account payable->invoice journal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such direct relation.

Usually the invoice issuer provide a payment id (from the payment slip) to be used on the payment. When paying you are supposed to provide the payment id but no law of nature force you to do so.

The payment id may be an invoice id, a customer id, a combination of the two, or some other unique identification of the payment.

All AX versions contain a field on the `LedgerJournalTrans` table called `PaymentId` for this purpose. It may be blank.